# java for loop pyramid

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to create a loop with a string so that with each successive loop, the last and first characters from the previous line will not be displayed. I'm also trying to print the length of each loop next to each line. It will look like an upside-down pyramid.

I had this:

```
    for(int scounter = fullName.length(); scounter > 0; scounter--)
    for (String name : fullName)
    for(int counter = 0; counter < fullName.length(); counter++)

     System.out.println(scounter + "[ " + fullName.substring(0, fullName.length() counter)+ " ]");
```

It prints something like this:

```
   24******
   24****
   24**
   24*
```

Yet I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
    7*******
     5*****
      4***
       1*
```

Comment: should the length be 7, 5, 3, 1?

Comment: the code provided has nothing to do with inverted pyramid!! is there something missing?

Comment: @gigadot: that would be too logical!

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "*******";
for (int i = 0, l = str.length(); i <= l/2; i++) {
  String line = str.substring(i, l - i);
  System.out.printf("%" + (i + 1) + "d%s\n", line.length(), line);
}
```

This will [print](http://ideone.com/OH7f5):

```
7*******
 5*****
  3***
   1*
```

I'm assuming you meant `3` instead of `4` in your example, that is, that you want to decrement by `2`.

Answer (score 1):

I started working on this problem and found my solution to be slightly different from Joao's. Hope this helps!

```
public class pyramid
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i=0, sz=args[0].length();i<sz; ++i,--sz)
    {
      System.out.printf("%"+(i+1)+"d%s\n", sz-i, args[0].substring(i,sz));
    }
}

}
```

Invocation as per request:

```
java pyramid abcdefg
7abcdefg
 5bcdef
  3cde
   1d

java pyramid abcdef
6abcdef
 4bcde
  2cd
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not match the words of your question, so here's a method that behaves according to your words as I understand them:

```
public void pyramid(String text) {
    int len = text.length();
    int start = 0;
    while (start < len) {
        for (int i = 0; i < start; ++i) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(text.substring(start, len));
        ++start;
        --len;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
        for(int k = 3;k>=i; k--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
    for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for(int n = 2; n<=i;n++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }   
                        
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
        for(int m = 1 ;m<=3; m++){
            for(int o = 1;o<=m; o++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int p = 3;p>=m;p--){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for(int q = 2;q>=m;q--){
                System.out.print("*");      
            }   
            
            System.out.println();
        }   
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).